# searching and counting in a part of file in vim

Tags: vim

How to count how many `-` symbols are there in a particular section of a file. The `-` will be at the begining of line. Section starts and ends with a particular word.

I read byte of vim pdf. I could not find how to extract a particular section from a file and search in that.

By using `:/^-` I can get `-` at the beginning of each line.. but It will give all `-` symbols in the whole file.. and It just highlights.. How can I get the count of `-` symbols in a particular section of the file??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say the sections you are interested in are delimited by lines containing words `begin` and `end` respectively. Then you can do following:

```
:g/begin/,/end/ s/^-//gn
```

This will tell you the count of the  `-` signs.

My references are http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges and http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Count_number_of_matches_of_a_pattern